# How to change the default view of the "extend" page in a custom administration theme

Tags: theming, 8

I am building an admin theme for Drupal 8.

I want to provide the extended page of another layout.

**Default extend page**: /admin/modules

Screenshot:

[image]

**What I'm trying to change:**

I want to create a custom layout for the modules list that would look something like this:

[image]

There are so much twig templates but can't find the templates of the administration pages. These are the one I want overridden by my custom layout (see picture above)

The question is where to find the template for overriding that ?

Comment: That is the toolbar module, it is unrelated to the theme.

Comment: Yes, I know.
But the question is that all that content I will re-style in a different way so that is more UX/User-friendly. I don't like the default administrations themes. Concrete how can i change/put that in my custom theme ?

Comment: _I will re-style in a different way_. Without knowing what you want, how do you expect us to help? Please edit the question and include what you want to change...

Comment: Could you include the exact path of the page you're actually looking to change.

Comment: yes, it's /admin/modules